# using jquery find parent html element and append css class on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

If I have code like this inside my view page

```
<li>
     <a class="selected" href="/">Some link</a>
</li>
```

how can I use jquery to find this element (with selected class) and append to it's parent li element some css class, result should be like this

```
   <li class="some-class">
      <a class="selected" href="/">Some link</a>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 4):

use:

```
$('.selected').parent().addClass('some-class')
```

or

```
$('.selected').closest('li').addClass('some-class')
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Jquery you can use the parent function: https://api.jquery.com/parent/

Answer (score 0):

https://api.jquery.com/parent/

```
$(".selected").parent().addClass("some-class")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**.parent()**](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

```
$('.selected').parent().addClass('some-class')
```

or [**.closest()**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$('.selected').closest('li').addClass('some-class')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get parent by jquery parent api doc:

https://api.jquery.com/parent/

try like this:

```
$(".selected").parent().addClass("some-class");
```

or

```
$(".selected").parent("li").addClass("some-class");
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/50/